# How to reproduce the behavior of SQL NVARCHAR in Python when generating a SHA-512 hash?

Tags: python, sql, encoding, hashlib

I have the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(254), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), '2020-05-27 00:00:00.000', 127)), 2)
```

that generates the hash value

```
E8FD9193FA939608DF127AC73428EB39F66CB6F44440083EF269A1F72176BF7BF80C3EB26BA43277E6F9CFFB4F7AFC6AA83AF527BEDF887E4EE06BA492CAD3BE
```

out of todays date and I want to reproduce this hash in Python with

```py
hashlib.sha512('2020-05-27 00:00:00.000'.encode()).hexdigest().upper()
```

but I get

```
FE48F900755B4C19039E6886148566DF93730A7887771C7A72260BB4E784080CDDA6C70C428A6EEFED658846F45F3D153C6B6472C04508B9242C14C61BD1C1BE
```

as hash value. When I use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR I get the correct hash value. How can I reproduce the bahavior of NVARCHAR in Python?

Comment: Consider: You are hashing bytes and are not once giving a target string encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVARCHAR encodes to UTF-16LE. Adding it to

```py
hashlib.sha512('2020-05-27 00:00:00.000'.encode('utf_16_le')).hexdigest().upper()
```

creates the correct hash value.

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar and default python strings are both supposed to be unicode and multi byte characters. However, there are two more sub types. Big Endian and Little Endian where they differ. Low endian will work for you. Use 'utf-16le' encoding to get the answer you want.

```js
hashlib.sha512('2020-05-27 00:00:00.000'.encode('utf-16le')).hexdigest().upper()
```