# How to convert hashbytes string from sql to spark equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, databricks

I have a process using the following select statement in sql server

```
SELECT  HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST('4100119300' AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS StringConverted
```

This give you: 0x66A2F63C04A3A85347AD2F5CD99F1113F1BDD9CE

I have been trying to re-create this same result in Spark SQL without luck.

I tried this `sha1(encode('4100119300','utf-8'))` in Spark

But the result of this is: b4cf5aae8ce3dc1673da4949cfdf2edfa33fdba4

During my test if I remove the cast in the sql area the result is the same in spark. The problem I see is that in spark you can't specify the size of the string or maybe is changing the encoding in the process. I already have data in sql hashed with the nvarchar(100) and is not possible to remove it from the spark equivalent.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `sha1(encode('4100119300','utf-8')` is hashing a UTF-8 encoded string. `select  hashbytes('SHA1', CAST('4100119300' as nvarchar(100)))` is hashing a UCS-2 encoded string (i.e.: two bytes per character). This is why you get different answers.

Comment: With USC-2 you mean UTF-16 ?

Comment: No, I specifically mean UCS-2. This is not the same thing as UTF-16. While you can read and write UTF-16 data into nchar/nvarchar/ntext fields from an application none of the SQL Server string functions will give you correct results in the presence of Supplementary Characters unless the current database is using a Supplementary Character (_SC) collation.

Comment: e.g.: Try the following test with the U+1F600 Grinning Face emoji character: `select nchar(128512)` in a database with the default en-US collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, then repeat the same in a database with `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`. In the first database `nchar(128512)` returns null, in the second you'll get your Grinning Face emoji.

Comment: So I have to find a way to encode the string to USC-2 and then run the hash function in Spark?

I was thinking the nvarchar cast converted the string to utf and tried the utf-8 and 16 in spark without luck. I will try to find this conversion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have You seen those differences?

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST('4100119300' AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS StringConverted
-- 0x66A2F63C04A3A85347AD2F5CD99F1113F1BDD9CE
```

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', '4100119300') AS StringConverted
-- 0xB4CF5AAE8CE3DC1673DA4949CFDF2EDFA33FDBA4
```

To store varbytes as string I use CONVERT with `style = 1` flag ([CAST & CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles))

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), HASHBYTES('SHA1', '4100119300'), 1) AS StringConverted
```

And **this** is what You are looking for. It's simply Sparks `b4cf5aae8ce3dc1673da4949cfdf2edfa33fdba4` in lowercase  and without `0x` prefix.

Comment: Yes the problem is because we have data that was hash with the first select using the cast inside the hashbytes that I get the different hash. Yes I tried your second and third approach and using the sha1 in Spark I get the same result, thanks.

Comment: The result 0x66A2F63C04A3A85347AD2F5CD99F1113F1BDD9CE is actually the result I want to replicate in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to highlight here is that Varchar to NVarchar relates to encoding so you just need the same encoding to regenerate the Hash Key which is 'utf_16_le' encoding.

For regeneration of :

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(254), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), '2020-05-27 00:00:00.000', 127)), 2)`

You will need something like this in Pyspark :

`hashlib.sha512('2020-05-27 00:00:00.000'.encode('utf_16_le')).hexdigest().upper()`

Link to related issue: [How to reproduce the behavior of SQL NVARCHAR in Python when generating a SHA-512 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039570/how-to-reproduce-the-behavior-of-sql-nvarchar-in-python-when-generating-a-sha-51)

Hope that Helps. Thanks